# Lost email to Steam

Tags: steam

I was resetting my PC, when I got it up and running again I had forgotten which email I used for Steam. When I tried to login, Steam Guard wanted me to confirm the email that I didn't have.

I tried looking through the Steam support (of course they don't have a contact email) but anyhow, I clicked the "not receiving Steam Guard code" and it prompted me to insert my username email or phone number, but none of those work. Not sure why my username (Vior) is not working (obviously it's not the username of the account, but I don't know how to get that without being in the account)

This is [my Steam page](https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199103680667).

I hope someone can help me with my issues.
Thank you for reading and help.

Comment: Is Vior your display name, or your username? There's a difference for Steam.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Steam support](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithLogin) and select the following:

1. Help me sign into my account
2. I forgot my Steam Account Name or Password
3. Try every email you have used in the past
4. When you find the email that you used, select either "email an account verification to me@email.com" if you can access that email, or "I no longer have access to that email address."

If you not only cannot remember which email you used, but used an email that you cannot remember, things get more difficult.

1. You will need to get through the automated system. Enter "fart@gmail.com" as your address. You need an address associated with an account, this is. No, I don't know who the real Fart is but I hope they don't mind.
2. Select "I no longer have access to this email address"
3. Enter as much information as you can into the form. Make it clear which account this is actually about and give any info you can, with the exception of card details.
4. Follow any instructions given. They won't make it easy- don't argue with or get frustrated by this. Right now I have as much info about your account as you seem to, but I'm sure you don't want them to let me steal your account.

Comment: Please cite the source you used.

Comment: @Joachim Going to the Steam Support page and pressing options until I found the most likely ones to work.

Comment: It's always good to have a link in your post itself, so others can verify your answer. You did give a walkthrough of how you got there, so it's obvious you didn't plagiarize something. (Nice username, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

contact Steam Support for account recovery even if you've forgotten the account's email address, password, and phone number. as instructed for the search will help Steam identify your account, or present other options for locating an account if the email address is incorrect.

Comment: Your second sentence is missing a verb. What does "As instructed" mean or refer to?